# Rest API GET Method using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin

Tags: c#, api, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

i'm new on creating Rest API using PHP. I have create one, my codes works but i'm not sure about it, here is the code :

```
// connect to the mysql database
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database',$link);

// retrieve the table and key from the path
$nama_tujuan = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
$nama_tabel = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
//Menu Login
if($nama_tujuan=="login")
{

$username = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
$password = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($request));
    if($method=='GET')
    {
        $sql = "select * from $nama_tabel where username_reg='$username' and pass_reg='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$link);
        if (!$result) {
          http_response_code(404);
          die(mysql_error());
        }
                 $cek_user=mysql_num_rows($result);
                 //cek user
                 if($cek_user==1)
                 {
                     //Kirim data yang dperlukan
                     for ($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($result);$i++) 
                        {
                            echo ($i>0?',':'').json_encode(mysql_fetch_object($result));
                        }
                 }
    }
}
```

for example i try it with:

```
http://localhost/api.php/login/member/neo/qw
```

and it show all of the fields like this :

```
{"nik":"46464646457349187","username_reg":"neo","nm_dpn_reg":"neo","nm_blg_reg":"alit","email_reg":"neo@neo.com","pass_reg":"qw","jns_kel":"P","pin_reg":"111111","tmp_lahir_reg":"lumajang","tgl_lahir_reg":"1-1-1945","alamat_reg":"jolotundo","kota_reg":"surabaya","kd_pos":"60131","propinsi":"Aceh","alamat_kirim":"","kota_kirim":"","kdpos_kirim":"","propinsi_kirim":"","wilayah":"jawa","tlp_hp_reg":"08964507555","tgl_daf":"2016-04-27 16:32:00","ikut_resel":"","bonus":"0"}
```

Is this called Rest API? And my second question, i want to get JSON data on my Android app, i'm using Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin. I already create some code, but i don't know the rest, because i'm new on developing android app. Here is my activity code :

```
             button.Click += async (sender, e) => {

            string url = "http://localhost/api.php/login/login_mbr/" +
                         txtUsername.Text +
                         "/" +
                         txtPassword.Text;


            string m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(await FetchWeatherAsync(url));
            // ParseAndDisplay (json);
        };
    }
    private async Task<string> FetchWeatherAsync(string url)
    {
        // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

    }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the json string by this:

```
private async Task<string> FetchWeatherAsync (string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
        {
             string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
             return strContent;
        }
    }
}
```

now this already returns you the JSON.

If you want to deserialize the JSON into the object you should create the object with the specified properties like:

```
public class WeatherResult ()
{
    public string nik {get; set;}

      public string username_reg {get; set;}
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

and then you can get it by

```
WeatherObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResult>(await FetchWeatherAsync(url));
```

If you don't want to create new object you can use dynamic object

```
dynamic result = JObject.Parse(await FetchWeatherAsync(url));
```

Note: you need `Newtonsoft` library for JSON.

Comment: You made my day!

i create object with specified properties to get it. Thanks :D

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it.

Comment: but it isn't waiting, need to wait until the end of process then do the next method. Do i missed something?

Comment: @neneo I am not sure what do you mean, please be more specific, thanks

Comment: sorry, here is my prob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200636/async-await-not-wait-the-process-using-visual-studio-and-xamarin

Comment: @neneo check my answer